# Trying to view CM and DM components of a signal on a two channel digital scope screen

Tags: oscilloscope, differential, common-mode

I want learn how to view the CM and DM components of a signal on a usual two channel scope. The reason for this to be able to verify whether a noise superimposed on a signal is CM orDM.

Regarding my below drawing, I thought if I can measure Va and Vb with two seperate channels I might use the MATH function to see the CM and DM components. Imagine Test Device in the figure is a power supply with its plus and negative terminals shown and you observed noise/interference at some point by a scope.

And now you want to check whether what you have seen as noise is due to CM or DM interference.

Would the following setup work:

[image]
In this case about the figure above I’m stuck at two points:

Where should be the probe ground leads be connected?

What would plot the CM and DM if MATH function is used? Would Ch1+Ch2 plot the common mode part of the signal?

Comment: (A + X) - (B + X) = A - B = differential

Comment: How about the CM? And where should be the scope groundleeds be grouded?

Comment: DM = differential. You can try it without grounds connected for differential measurements.

Comment: Sorry I would write how about CM

Comment: Use two resistors forming a node between A and B and measure at that node. If A and B are balanced differential signals then that measurement gives common mode signal.

Comment: @Andyaka Interesting; would you fancy an answer with a schematics about this?

Comment: @user164567 two resistors. From A to B. in the middle, a node. Isn't that explicit enough?